# Intellisense doesn't work with an upgraded solution from vs 2005 in vs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

I converted a VS2005 solution to VS2008, but Intellisense isn't working. It works fine with a native solution made in VS2008. Its a C# solution.

Answer (score 2):

**For VC++:**

1. Close your solution
2. Delete your .ncb file
3. Open your solution again

By the way VC++'s intellisense is re-written in VS2010 to be much better.

**For C#:**

For C# projects Intellisense is stored in projdata files.  (Do a backup before deleting just in case it has something else in there)

Another thing to check for C#:

Go to: Tools | Options | Text Editor | C#

Make sure `Auto list memebers` is on, and `Parameter information` is on,

Comment: Sorry but its not a VC++. Its a C# Solution - WebService.

Comment: Ive found them. What do i need to do with them?

Comment: @GutierrezDev: Back them up first just in case but just delete them then re-open your project.

Comment: Nothing. Something i've seeing is that it isnt checking errors. This is a problem too.

Comment: @GutierrezDev: Isn't checking errors? How about a new project does that work? If not I suggest uninstalling and then reinstalling.

Comment: The Problem is with Vs2005 projects. Vs2008 is ok with new and old vs2008.